# Integral formula for a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am working through some problems in complex analysis, and am stumped by the following:

Let $f$ be an analytic function in the disk $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<R\}$ and $\gamma$ be the counterclockwise oriented circle $|\zeta|=r$ where $0<r<R$. For any point $z$ such that $|z|<r$, prove that
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma f(\zeta)\left(\frac{1}{\zeta-z}-\frac{1}{\zeta- (r^2 / \bar{z})}\right)d\zeta$$

If I'm not mistaken, we should have Cauchy's integral formula stating
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}d\zeta$$

So, is the problem asking to show that
$$\int_\gamma \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-\frac{r^2}{\bar{z}}}d\zeta=0?$$

If so, how do we do this? (I'm not even sure where to start)

Comment: prove that your expression is equal to ... what?

Comment: $\zeta \neq \frac {r^{2}} {\overline z}$ for $|z| <r$ and $|\zeta|=r$. Apply Cauchy's Theorem.

Comment: @geetha290krm That works, thanks.